# Convert text/string response to html

Tags: javascript

Inside my fetch POST, I am receiving an html response in plain text. I want to select the relevant part and then display it in my web page, so I'm doing:

```
 document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

  fetch("", {

    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      body: document.querySelector('#new_message').value
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken')
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => {
    document.querySelector('#new_message').value = ""
    let div = document.createElement('div')
 
    fetch("", {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "charset=UTF-8",
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result2 => {

        var success = $(result2).filter("#granpost"+result['id']); 
        div.append(success);

        document.querySelector('#plis').append(div);
        console.log(success); // div#success  
    });



  });

}
```

This is what I wan the code to do:
First, convert the string to html, then, get the div with the id `"granpost"+result['id']` and store it in `success` variable. Finally, display that `success` div in my page.

This is not working, the only thing that gets displayed in my page is this: '[object Object]'

And the console.log is returning this: `m.fn.init [prevObject: m.fn.init(45), context: undefined]`

Comment: What is `result` and result2 and what element should they match? No way for us to debug what is shown without more detail. Oh I see an issue.. Can't append a jQuery object with native `append()`. Try `$('#plis').append(div)`

Comment: I've just added the whole fetch

Comment: We still don't know what `result` and `result2` values are but definitely try changing to `$('#plis').append(div)`

Comment: You have `result['id']`, but result is a string.....

Comment: @epascarello ``result2`` is a string, it's the whole html template in plain text. ``result`` comes from a jsonresponse

Comment: It is a string.... `.then(response => response.text())
  .then(result`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue, response is a string and you are using it as an object. So looks like

```
.then(response => response.text())
.then(result => {})
```

should be using json

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(result => {})
```

---

Now with the output:

You are mixing DOM and jQuery. So you are appending a jQuery object to a DOM element. Hence why you are getting a reference to an object in the HTML. Change

```
let div = document.createElement('div')
```

to

```
const div = $('<div></div>')
```

And change

```
document.querySelector('#plis').append(div);
```

to

```
$('#plis').append(div);
```

---

You also are using filter with an id. filter is running off the elements on the level it has. And since it is an id, I assume you have one. So you should be using find.

```
var success = $(result2).find("#granpost"+result['id']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately nothing is being appended now. Not even "[object Object]"

Comment: because of the `result['id']` issue I pointed out in the comments. looks like you used text() when you meant json()

Comment: You are right. But somehow it's still not showing anything

Comment: debug it.... console.log() and figure out what is happening. My guess is it is not finding the element. I can only guess

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:
Change the parent response of this fetch to `.json()` and then:

````
fetch("", {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "charset=UTF-8",
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result2 => {


        var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(result2, "text/html");

        je = doc.querySelector(`#granpost${result['id']}`)


        div.append(je);

        $('#plis').append(div);
    });
```
````